# How do I create a default fallback profile for any process that doesn't have one in AppArmor?

Tags: security, apparmor

Is there a way to specify a default profile on any executable that doesn't have a profile already defined?

The idea is to avoid any unconstrained processes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the mailing list, there *could* be a way to generate such a default profile in this way:

```
profile default /** {
  #insert default profile rules here
}
```

sources: [Generate a default/fallback profile? No blacklisting](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/apparmor/2012-December/003240.html) and the responses that follow.

Note that "Currently setting a default profile that applies to the whole system from boot is a bit of a pain but we do have plans to improve that. Unfortunately there is enough other work happen that I don't see it happen soon." from John Johansen's response [here](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/apparmor/2012-December/003241.html).
Anyone interested is requested to read the thread in its entirety.