# How does AppArmor deal with non-profiled Programs?

Tags: security, apparmor

I setup and configured AppArmor in Ubuntu and I would like to know how AppArmor deals with Packages and Applications which have no AppArmor Profile?

After installing the package with `sudo apt-get install apparmor-profiles`, I have 175 profiles reported as loaded from `aa-status`

I cannot imagine I have only 175 programs installed on my box, and I would like to know what AppArmor does to prevent security breaches in programs that have no profile.

Comment: A famous example for a potentially vulnerable software without active profile is the firefox browser.

Answer (score 3):

Accrding to the [http://wiki.apparmor.net](http://wiki.apparmor.net/index.php/FAQ#Is_AppArmor_policy_Default_Deny_.28White_listing.29) FAQ any program that has no profile is basically unprotected / unconstrained and can do any mischief in Ubuntu, almost in the same way as there would not have been any AppArmor in the first place

Comment: Right. it doesn't have a profile, so it isn't sandboxed, so it has free reign.

Comment: @jrg: There is no kind of "fallback profile" / "defaul rule" for the unprofiled program?

Comment: From what I understand, no. Not at this point. Eventually they want to do LXC sandboxing (from what I've heard) for everything - so everything will be sandboxed, and then specific things will be whitelisted for everything.

Comment: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/AppArmorProfiles

Comment: @jrg: (1) Nice list (few packages covered though..:( (2) The irony is that LXC says [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/lxc.html#lxc-security): "sorry not safe yet". Kind of defering the purpose of using a "linux container" in the first place, when its rather likely to be not safe. At present I cannot manage to get Ubunut safe neither via LXC nor AppArmor.

Comment: @humanityANDpeace A day later you seem to found a solution to the problem Care to update your answer? https://askubuntu.com/a/231043/388226

Answer (score 2):

First, the background of AppArmor:

> AppArmor's security model is to bind access control attributes to programs rather than to users.
>
> > AppArmor profiles can be in one of two modes: enforcement and complain.

*[via the Ubuntu Security Team's wiki page](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor)*

So, enforcement enforced whatever rules (for more details on that, [take a look here](https://askubuntu.com/a/50835/6005)) are defined, and complain just logs attempts to violate policy to the syslog (most of the time).

Some supported profiles are:

- Cups (cupsd)
- MySQL (mysqld)
- Evince (PDF viewer on Ubuntu - enabled by default).
- Firefox (Will be disabled by default and be opt-in for advanced users)
- Apache (webserver, ditto)
- and the list goes on, but not long enough. [Full list is here.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/AppArmorProfiles)

Notable exceptions are:

- Chrom(ium)e. While they do have a [AppArmor profile on their wiki](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSandboxing), doesn't seem like anyone uses it.
- I didn't see empathy, pidgin or transmission on this list, or anything similar to them.

Lastly, someone else has asked a similar question about a [fallback profile for anything that isn't defined.](https://askubuntu.com/q/140573/6005)

But the answer is, by default, if a application doesn't have a profile in AppArmor, it will have access to everything - it won't be sandboxed.

However, on 12.10 Chrome will run inside a seccomp-bpf sandbox, which had it's modules backported from version 3.5 of the Linux Kernel to the 3.2 series that 12.10 is using by Canonical.

Comment: I like the linked question about the "fallback profile". Seems you also put a bounty on it. Great! I have a very poor repu, so I cannot join, elsewise I would consider.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite interesting that @humanityANDpeace answered no to the question while providing a solution [in another thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/231043/388226).

Anyway, here is the answer for completeness sake:

```
profile default /** {
  #insert default profile rules here
}
```

[Source](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/apparmor/2012-December/003241.html)

Comment: So the answer is "no", right. There's no `default` profile added by default, you have to make one?

Comment: AppArmor does not deal with non-profiled programs by default but you can write a fallback ("default") profile to deal with; as I understood (I haven't tried myself either.)